# preg_replace new statement to find variables

Tags: preg-replace

Hi at the moment I use preg_replace to replace a variable like "$money" with a text. Now I have changed my vars to "%%money%%" what I must changed in the preg_replace statement?

```
preg_replace("@\\$" . $var . "([^a-zA-Z_0-9\x7f-\xff]|$)@", $value . "\\1", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace("@%%" . $var . "([^a-zA-Z_0-9\x7f-\xff]?)%%$@", $value . "$1", $text);
```